Multi stage build with poetry and gunicorn not working: Gunicorn not found
I'm hoping somebody can help me, I'm probably missing something very simple but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to switch to poetry for my python dependency management. But I'm bumping into an issue with my multi stage docker build.
When I build a single stage image I can just run gunicorn any where in the shell because it is add to the env paths. see my docker below.
FROM python:3.12.2-slim-bookworm as builder

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1 \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache \
    VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT_PATH="/app/.venv" 

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install poetry

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN poetry install --no-root  && rm -rf $POETRY_CACHE_DIR

ENV PATH="/app/.venv/bin:$PATH"

But when I try to create a multi stage build like below, the executable is copied, and added to the path, but I get the error "gunicorn: not found" The file is there but not executable.
FROM python:3.12.2-slim-bookworm as builder

ENV POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1 \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache \
    VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT_PATH="/app/.venv" 

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install poetry

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN poetry install --no-root  && rm -rf $POETRY_CACHE_DIR


# ######## RUNTIME ########

FROM python:3.12.2-bookworm as runtime

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1 \

WORKDIR /app2

COPY --from=builder /app/. /app2

ENV PATH="/app2/.venv/bin:$PATH"

When I login to the docker shell I see that the gunicorn file is copied to /app2/.venv/bin folder, that folder is added to my path environment variable, but when I try to run it I get gunicorn: not found.
The command "which gunicorn" returns: /app2/.venv/bin/gunicorn

Python virtual environments tend to be fairly specific to both the exact Python version being used and the exact directory name that's used.  Does it work better if you use the same FROM line in both build stages, and if you use the same filesystem path /app in the second stage without renaming it?

yes, that is the issue. I kept the VNV in the same directory name and it is working.  Now I'd like to figure out why, but at lease i can continue

Python virtual environments aren't especially portable.  They must be in the same filesystem directory where they were initially created, and they must use the exact same Python version as they were initially built with.
So, in the Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12.2-slim-bookworm as builder # <--
...                                         #   These two image names should match
FROM python:3.12.2-slim-bookworm as runtime # <--

COPY --from=builder /app/ /app/             # <-- Both paths need to match
ENV PATH="/app/.venv/bin:$PATH"             # <-- Needs to use same directory

If you just create a virtual environment and look inside it, you'll see these wrapper scripts have the absolute path to the virtual environment hard-coded in it.
$ head -1 $HOME/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/pip
#!/home/yourname/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/python3.12

If the virtual environment is moved to a different place, the absolute path in the "shebang" line won't match any more, and this results in the "not found" error when you try to run the script.
